# Switch to blog and get content from that blog

Tags: multisite, wp-query

Anyone thinks this should not work? I can't make it work for some reason.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    wp_query( 'p=' . $post_id );
});
```

The point is that instead of displaying whatever page I am about to display, I choose content from a different blog instead.

Comment: are `$blog_id` and `$post_id` in the scope? and also this code alone wont display the content.

Comment: $blog_id and $post_id are just placeholders for my example, so yes they are in the scope. This code will not in itself display the content, but further down the line the "Wordpress loop" will do it. Right? (I'm not getting 404, I actually display a page template but there is not content in it, one possible reason for this not working is that it's not getting invoked. But I think the hook is suitably chosen.)

Comment: try `get_header` as your hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people with the same issue who don't read comments the solution was to change the hook from `wp_head` to `get_header`